# WeakReference, reachabilityFence, and Java Memory Model

Tags: java, memory-model, java-memory-model

Suppose `ref` is a `WeakReference` object pointing to (or at a certain moment having pointed to) an object `obj`. If a call `ref.get()` happens-before (or at least precedes in the program order?) an execution of `Reference.reachabilityFence(obj)`, is there any chance that the returnee of the `ref.get()` may be null? (in addition, I want to ask this question again after replacing the part about the observation of null through `ref.get()` by the acquisition of the `ref` through queue polling.)

I ask this question because I am not quite sure how [Reference#reachabilityFence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#reachabilityFence(java.lang.Object)) works in terms of [Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4), especially when it interacts with [WeakReference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)s (and other similar references). The following list is all the places where specifications related to this topic exist, as far as I know:

- (a)[JSL 17.4.MemoryModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)
- (b)[JSL 12.6.Finalization of Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6), especially (b2)[12.6.2. Interaction with the Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.2)
- (c)[WeakReference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).
- (d)[Reference#reachabilityFence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#reachabilityFence(java.lang.Object))

The problem is that the terminology used in (c) and (d) is vague and unclear compared to the one used in (a) and (b).

If the answer to the question written at the beginning is sadly yes, how can I make all the `ref.get()` calls happening-before a certain point of code? If not, how can we prove that based on the specifications written in (a)(b)(c)(d) or anywhere else?

Although the answer to the first question may be enough for my use, I also want the specifications in (c) and in (d) to become clear, so let me ask more questions below.

First, (c)WeakReference says that **at a certain point of time** the gc determines objects to be weakly-reachable, at the same time clears weak refs, and at the same time declares those objects as finalizable. According to (b2), reachability checks and finalizability declarations take place at **reachability decision points**. So the "certain point of time" must be one of the reachability decision points, right **?** If so, other questions come up. (b2) also says reachability desicion points are NOT actual points (unlike writes and reads) in the code or on the program order; they are virtual points that are only related to actions through come-before / come-after relations, which are independent of program ordering. So... weak refs are cleared at the decision point, which is not anywhere on the code. What does it exactly mean **?** On what condition can `WeakReference#get()` be null? cannot be null? Is it the come-before / come-after relation between the decision point and the `WeakReference#get()` that we need? Or the come-before / after relation between the decision point and some other action which has a certain memory-model-related relation to the `WeakReference#get()`?

Next, (d)reachabilityFence. It says a call of this method keeps the object's strong reachability and
thus makes it unreclaimable until after the call. Can I interpret it as saying that the call keeps the object's strong reachability until after the call **?** Technically it is not saying so. But if there is no specification about until when the strong reachability are kept, the part about keeping the strong reachability is useless. (And the other half talking about the undefined concept "unreclaimability" is useless from the beginning.) So the strong reachability is maintained until after the call -- but what does the word 'after' exactly mean **?** Program order? Happens before? The order in which comissions take place? Besides, I think objects become unreachable at a certain decision point as described in (b2). What determines whether a certain call of reachabilityFence affects a certain decision point or it does not? The come-before / come-after relation between the fence and the decision point? Obviously not, because since the call of fence is neither a write nor a read nor a synchronization action, it makes no difference whether a certain fence call comes-before or comes-after a certain decision point.

I suspect (c) and (d) are too vague and thus it is impossible to answer basic questions like my first one.

Comment: I don’t get this part after “Next, (d)reachabilityFence.” The first sentence goes like “It says a call…”, followed by a question like “Can I interpret it as saying that the call…” using literally the same phrases of the preceding sentence. It’s not an interpretation at all when you assume that a sentence means literally what it says. But then, you proceed with “Technically it is not saying so”. There, I’m lost. When it says it, even literally, why isn’t it saying it “technically”?

Comment: First, sorry for my incomprehensible writing. My brain was a bit too mathematical, skeptical, and inflexible. But let me explain what I meant. The doc says [it keeps strong reachability (but not saying until when)] and [makes the object unreclaimable (<- undefined word) until the call].  I wanted to make clear whether I could or could not join these two statements and say [keeps strong reachability until the call], although it is almost trivial.

Comment: It doesn’t say “*and*”, it says “remains strongly reachable… *thus* the referenced object is not reclaimable”. The latter is a consequence of the former, so even if you assume that in this sentence “at least until” refers to the latter only, it must apply to the former due to the logical dependency. Regarding the meaning of “at least until” in term of JMM, mind the statement “*This method is applicable only when reclamation may have visible effects, which is possible for objects with finalizers…*” The ordering is about the actions before the fence and visible effects in finalizers or cleaners.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question : No. And that is exactly what the documentation says:

> Ensures that the object referenced by the given reference **remains strongly reachable, regardless of any prior actions of the program that might otherwise cause the object to become unreachable**; thus, the referenced object is not  reclaimable by garbage collection **at least until after the invocation of this method**

So calling `Reference.reachabilityFence(obj)` establishes a `strong reference` to `obj`. It does not matter what that `obj` was wrapped in a `WeakReference` (so that "...might otherwise cause the object to become unreachable..."), it will stay strongly reachable.

I am not exactly sure what you are looking for with *at a certain point of time*, but may be this will help. A `GC` cycle might scan (and as such discover weak references) only partial regions of the heap. It can scan only *some* regions (in case of regionalized collectors like `G1`) and thus simply skip the regions where your `weak reference` might be located. That means the discovery and clearing of weak references is non-deterministic. Some GC algorithms even have scheduled collection of these special references : that is even if they discover it now, they might skip clearing it for next `X` cycles. You can effectively *delay* clearing such a reference on purpose (`ShenandoahRefProcFrequency`).  It *will* happen, but unknown when, neither in what GC cycle.

That is probably what *reachability decision points* is. This decision is made at the point when a GC encounters such a special reference.

I am also not exactly sure where confusion comes from with the word `after`. Since the call of `Reference.reachabilityFence(obj);` should normally happen only in a method, that to me is program order, which according to the `JLS` *is* also `happens-before` relationship.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer and comprehensive explanation about how GC works. But this is not the point I care about. I care mainly about the reordering of the execution (and inter-thread interaction) --- which I think is the main point of JLS (a) and (b2).

Comment: But I guess you may be right about reachabilityFence. The sample codes there seem to imply that a fence affects at least actions preceding the fence in the program order. If so, I assume all the actions happening-before a fence are affected, because java would be so unintuitive if not. (It is not logically deduced from the former, as you did.)
And I really want to distinguish what is guaranteed by the specs, what may be guessed from the specs, and how the common jvm impl behaves. This is the second one, right?